# Liferay with CAS and LDAP, access to external web page

Tags: jsp, ldap, liferay, cas

I'm working with liferay and implemented cas+ldap and it is working fine in the server, now I got a question, how can I create a portlet to redirect to an external URL and use the same user who was authenticated in liferay?

I tried

```
public class gotoURL extends MVCPortlet throws IOException {   
    private String sessionID = null;

    public void addDetails(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
        Cookie[] c =request.getCookies();
        for(int i =0;i<c.length;i++){                   
            if(c[i].getName().equals("JSESSIONID")){
                sessionID = c[i].getValue();
            }
        }       
        response.encodeURL("my_external_web");      
        response.sendRedirect("my_external_web");           
    }
}
```

i've also tried to make an iFrame into the liferay portal and pass the `@screen_name@` and `@password@` but it did't work(the another web is http and have a captchat).

Can i pass the jsessionid or similar to authenticate in another web page without have access to modify that application or i need to modifiy the external web page? in this case, what i need to add in the external web? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> Can i pass the jsessionid or similar to authenticate in another web
>   page without have access to modify that application or i need to
>   modifiy the external web page?

That actually depends.When you say an external URL,are you referring to an external application on the same web server or a different web server.It is possible on same web server,provided the jsession id configuration is done correctly on the server end.

> in this case, what i need to add in the external web?

Considering you are interacting with an application on a different server,you need to set up some mechanism such as [OAuth](http://oauth.net/code) to authenticate user on different application

Comment: Is in another server, but i'm using cas+ldap for the sso, i need to implement OAuth too for make this works?

Comment: So using CAS will be feasible option when that other application of yours supports authentication via same,else OAuth would be required for the same.